# One liner to append a file into another file but only if it hasn't already been added

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have an automated process that has a number of lines like the following pattern:

```
sudo cat /some/path/to/a/file >> /some/other/file
```

I'd like to transform that into a one liner that will only append to `/some/other/file` if `/some/path/to/a/file` has not already been added.

**Edit**
It's clear I need some examples here.

example 1:  Updating a .bashrc script for a specific login

example 2:  Creating a .screenrc for different logins

example 3:  Appending to the end of a /etc/ config file

Some other caveats.  The text is going to be added in a block (>>).  Consequently, it should be relatively straight forward to see if the entire code block is added or not near the end of a file.  I am trying to come up with a simple method for determining whether or not the file has already been appended to the original.

Thanks!

Example python script...

```py
def check_for_appended(new_file, original_file):
    """ Checks original_file to see if it has the contents of new_file """
    new_lines = reversed(new_file.split("\n"))
    original_lines = reversed(original_file.split("\n"))
    appended = None
    for new_line, orig_line in zip(new_lines, original_lines):
        if new_line != orig_line:
            appended = False
            break
        else:
            appended = True
    return appended
```

Comment: How can we tell? Let's say `/some/path/to/a/file` just contains the word `foo` and `/some/other/file` coincidentally already contains the word `foo`. How can we tell if `foo` exists in `/some/other/file` as a result of previously appending `/some/path/to/a/file`or not? Provide more explanation plus some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why one-liner? I mean, if you put several commands in a script, it'd be one-liner too.

Comment: @EdMorton given the example, the entire contents of the file should be in a single block.  So no need to look for individual words.

Comment: @purplehuman I may have incorrectly surmised that this was an easy to solve problem.  It feels like someone would have already solved this through some combination of sed and awk.

Comment: @Brian Bruggeman, I agree with what Ed Morton is asking you to do and you might also want to look at, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think this isn't possible with a one-liner and even a simple script. I'm not sure, but you may need to keep a log to add when a file added, because more than one file might have the same information in them, they might even be identical.

Comment: I could easily write a full python script.  But this feels dev-opsy enough that I would have expected a clear cut answer.

Comment: It is almost certainly trivial but you're going to have to tell us exactly what "it" is first before some of us will start thinking about a solution - right now there's just far too many possibilities for what you might need. And of course I used one word "foo" earlier as a placeholder for a block of text, no intent to imply I thought you were working with individual words.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will get you started - this GNU awk script:

```
gawk -v RS='^$' 'NR==FNR{f1=$0;next} {print (index($0,f1) ? "present" : "absent")}' file1 file2
```

will tell you if the contents of "file1" are present in "file2". It cannot tell you why, e.g. because you previously concatenated file1 onto the end of file2.

Is that all you need? If not update your question to clarify/explain.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Op just told me in the comments that the files he wants to concatenate are bash scripts -- this brings us back to the good ole C preprocessor include guard tactics:

prepend every file with

```
 if [ -z "$__<filename>__" ]; then __<filename>__=1; else
```

(of course replacing `<filename>` with the name of the file) and at the end

```
 fi
```

this way, you surround the script in each file with a test for something that's only true once.

Comment: This wouldn't work if you need a line twice in the result. If one of the files has the same line twice, the result would be wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing he want's his *content* to be unique, since he obviously can't tell whether a file was added to another one without keeping track of the files (unless he actually wants to search the whole accumulator file for the new file as kind of "substring").

Comment: Would it make a difference if I said these files were system and user files? I'm debugging a provisioning script for vagrant and packer.io and I'd like to rerun my provision script when something fails.
`cat /some/addition/to/bash_rc`  >> `~/.bashrc`

Comment: No. Sorry. The problem here is that you can't tell if a file has been added to another -- there's no information anywhere to guess that from.

Comment: Ah wait --- this is something completely different! Now your file is no longer "any file", but a bash script! That makes a hell of a difference.

Comment: .... and hence my initial comment asking for sample input and expected output. I feel there is more of this onion still to be peeled :-).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a technique to see if a file contains another file

```
contains_file_in_file() {
    local small=$1
    local big=$2
    awk -v RS="" '{small=$0; getline; exit !index($0, small)}' "$small" "$big"
}

if ! contains_file_in_file /some/path/to/a/file /some/other/file; then 
    sudo cat /some/path/to/a/file >> /some/other/file
fi
```

Comment: that will fail if either file contains any blank lines. It also has the slight error potential of a partial match due to the RS swallowing newlines. You CAN solve it with any awk, but GNU awk is simplest since it allows multi-char RS and so you can write: `awk -v RS='^$' '...'` to get the whole file in `$0`. Not that I'd advocate use of getline here of course :-).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
sudo (set -o noclobber; date > /tmp/testfile)
```

noclobber prevents overwriting an existing file.

I think it doesn't, since you wrote you want to append something but this technique might help.

When the appending all occurs in one script, then use a flag:

```
if [ -z "${appended_the_file}" ]; then
   cat /some/path/to/a/file >> /some/other/file
   appended_the_file="Yes I have done it except for permission/right issues"
fi
```

I would continue into writing a `function appendOnce { .. }`, with the content above. If you really want an ugly oneliner (ugly: pain for the eye and colleague):

```
test -z "${ugly}" && cat /some/path/to/a/file >> /some/other/file && ugly="dirt"
```

Combining this with sudo:

```
test -z "${ugly}" && sudo "cat /some/path/to/a/file >> /some/other/file" && ugly="dirt"
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you want is a collection of script segments which can be run as a unit. Your approach -- making them into a single file -- is hard to maintain and subject to a variety of race conditions, making its implementation tricky.

A far simpler approach, similar to that used by most modern Linux distributions, is to create a directory of scripts, say `~/.bashrc.d` and keep each chunk as an individual file in that directory.

The driver (which replaces the concatenation of all those files) just runs the scripts in the directory one at a time:

```
 if [[ -d ~/.bashrc.d ]]; then
   for f in ~/.bashrc.d/*; do
     if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
       source "$f"
     fi
   done
 fi
```

To add a file from a skeleton directory, just make a new symlink.

```
add_fragment() {
  if [[ -f "$FRAGMENT_SKELETON/$1" ]]; then
    # The following will silently fail if the symlink already
    # exists. If you wanted to report that, you could add || echo...
    ln -s "$FRAGMENT_SKELETON/$1" "~/.bashrc.d/$1" 2>>/dev/null
  else
    echo "Not a valid fragment name: '$1'"
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

Of course, it is possible to effectively index the files by contents rather than by name. But in most cases, indexing by name will work better, because it is robust against editing the script fragment. If you used content checks (md5sum, for example), you would run the risk of having an old and a new version of the same fragment, both active, and without an obvious way to remove the old one.

But it should be straight-forward to adapt the above structure to whatever requirements and constraints you might have.

For example, if symlinks are not possible (because the skeleton and the instance do not share a filesystem, for example), then you can copy the files instead. You might want to avoid the copy if the file is already present and has the same content, but that's just for efficiency and it might not be very important if the script fragments are small. Alternatively, you could use `rsync` to keep the skeleton and the instance(s) in sync with each other; that would be a very reliable and low-maintenance solution.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.  I'm actually using packer.io to create a virtual box.  The script is easy to maintain from that perspective, but the files are not on the system before I start.  This is really for debugging when a script goes wrong.  I just thought it would have a simple answer.

Comment: @BrianBruggeman: it does have a simple answer; the one I gave :) Use a directory instead of a file. Directories are containers; objects you put into them do not lose their identity. Files, on the other hand, are just undifferentiated streams. Of course, you could build a container format and impose it on files, but why bother? You can just use directories.